# validating JSON posted to a CFC

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a CFC (call it proxy.cfc) that I'm using as a proxy for a simple API that I've written.  Everything has been going along just fine and a few partners are starting to use the API effectively.

However, one site that is attempting to post data isn't sending valid JSON and I can't seem tho figure how to gracefully handle this error.

A valid JSON string that is posted as a URL param may look like this:

```
{"apicomponent":"proxyRemoteAdd","apimethod":"add","apiarguments":{"ph_num":1212,"rbpid":999,"ph_exch":555,"state":"HI","address_1":"123 Main Street","address_2":"","rmtid":"PON83","last_name":"Smith","test":1,"zip":999999,"first_name":"Joe","email":"test@test.com","city":"Honolulu","type":"SP","ph_area":995},"apiauthkey":"abc123"}
```

And that works just fine.

However, if that string is truncated for any reason:

```
{"apicomponent":"proxyRemoteAdd","apimethod":"add","apiarguments":{"ph_num":1212,"rbpid":999,"ph_exch":555,"state":"HI"
```

I catch an exception as follows:  Exception: JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string

This is coming from my onError in Application.cfc.  I did add some code to isolate it in Application.cfc as follows:

```
<cfif ARGUMENTS.EXCEPTION.MESSAGE IS "JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string">
 <!--- do some stuff here ---> 
</cfif>
```

Is that the best way to handle that sort of error?  Is there anyway to pass it off to the proxy.cfc file so I can return an error message back to the posting client?  As it is now the Application.cfc is catching it and not even letting me get to the proxy.cfc file.

UPDATE - here's some specific code samples.  This is how I've been testing and will illustrate how the data gets posted:

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.domain.com/api/proxy.cfc" method="post" result="httpResult" charset="UTF-8">
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="method" value="apiauth"/>
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="argumentCollection" value="#jsData#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

"apiauth" is the method in the CFC that acts as the authorization and proxy.
The argument collection is a JSON string as shown below.  It lists a component (a different CFC), the method in that component, the authkey of the user accessing the AP, and then a JSON string called apiarguments which contains the arguments and data that get passed to the apicomponent listed.

The proxy CFC file looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="apiauth" access="remote" returntype="any" output="false" returnFormat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="apicomponent" required="yes" type="string"/>
    <cfargument name="apimethod" required="yes" type="string"/>
    <cfargument name="apiauthkey" required="yes" type="string"/>
    <cfargument name="apiarguments" required="yes" type="struct"/>
    <cfset var LOCAL = {}/>

    <cfif not isDefined("ARGUMENTS.apiauthkey")>
      <cfreturn THIS.NewErrorResponse("Error 401 Malformed Request.") />
    </cfif>
    <cfif not isDefined("ARGUMENTS.apicomponent")>
      <cfreturn THIS.NewErrorResponse("Error 402 Malformed Request.") />
    </cfif>     
    <cfif not isDefined("ARGUMENTS.apimethod")>
      <cfreturn THIS.NewErrorResponse("Error 403 Malformed Request.") />
    </cfif>

        <cfset LOCAL.checkpwResult = FALSE/>
        <cfset LOCAL.apicomponent = ARGUMENTS.apicomponent />
        <cfset LOCAL.apimethod = ARGUMENTS.apimethod />
```

At this point some other CFCs are access to check the API key and user ID # to make sure they can access the API.  If everything checks out there the data gets passed off to the correct component/method:

```
<cfinvoke component="#LOCAL.apicomponent#" method="#LOCAL.apimethod#" argumentcollection="#apiarguments#" returnvariable="LOCAL.Response.Data"/>
```

However the JSON exception is being thrown before this CFC can even be accessed by the Application.cfc file.  If I drop a quick cfmail in proxy.cfc to just dump and mail the arguments it doesn't even hit that.

Here's a chunk of the stack trace:

coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils$JSONParseOverflowException: JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string at 
coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils$ParserState.incrementOffset(JSONUtils.java:1999) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils$ParserState.incrementOffset(JSONUtils.java:1980) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseString(JSONUtils.java:1385) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseObject(JSONUtils.java:1074) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseStruct(JSONUtils.java:1178) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseObject(JSONUtils.java:1059) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseStruct(JSONUtils.java:1178) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseObject(JSONUtils.java:1059) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseJSON(JSONUtils.java:1028) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.deserializeJSON(JSONUtils.java:168) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.deserializeJSON(JSONUtils.java:128) at coldfusion.filter.FilterUtils.GetArgumentCollection(FilterUtils.java:50) at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:193) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:442) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) 
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:155) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:331) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at

Comment: How is the proxy.cfc invoked? ie Does the client pass the URL parameter to it directly, or through some other method? Can you post some code to illustrate the chain of events?

Comment: can you just check using `isJSON()` and then feed them an error message ?

Comment: I'm going to update the main question with some code samples

Comment: @MattBusche - no because the error seems to be thrown by Application.cfc before the data even gets posted to the proxy.cfc.

Comment: I do not see anything obviously JSON related in the new code.  Look at the stack trace captured by `onError`. Specifically what line of code (or what part of your code) triggers the "JSON parsing failure:..." error.

Comment: @Leigh Is there something in the CF10 admin that checks for this that is throwing the error?  I'm adding a portion of the stack trace above

Comment: Is it possible that the URL is being truncated by a browser URL length limitation? Does this error happen if the same data is POSTed in the body of a request to the API instead of as part of the querystring?

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo - not by CF it isn't as my tests with a lot longer URLs work fine.  However, you may have hit on something with our firewall.  I'll see if I can test this externally and see what happens.

Comment: RE: Error - Just a guess, but when you use `argumentCollection="#apiarguments#"` with a string I think it is treating it as JSON in order to convert the arguments into a structure. Hence the error when the received value is not valid JSON. But agreed, you should try and figure out why the param string is being truncated.

Comment: I checked our firewall and URLs are limited to 2048 so definitely not that.  I also setup a hosting account outside our network and I can post fine, so whatever is truncating their JSON seems to be their problem and not mine.  I think my best bet is to just flesh out my error handling to make sure these are trapped and logged accordingly.  Interesting thought on a string to argumentCollection being treated as JSON.  I'd like to find confirmation of that.  Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If your argument is always a JSON string, you should be able to change the argument type to string, and pass it in that way (it will make it through Application.cfc) and then validate it within your apiAuth function using isJSON() - you should be validating it against malicious JSON anyways, so it won't be much code to initially check against isJSON(). This way, your API will give meaningful feedback and keep all the code where it should be.

However if you have other users passing an actual struct into your method, that won't work.

And you will definitely want to find out why the JSON string is being truncated. At a guess I would suggest there might be some un-escaped characters being passed in which is truncating the string early...

Comment: Thanks Marty.  It is another user passing that data in - I just used argumentcollection='' in my example since that how I had setup to do my testing.  The user that was causing the error worked fine in his test environment and then broke when he went to production, so at this point (seeing that no one else has the issue) I'm going to assume it was something on his end.